# Замена PDF путём смены src в тэге <embed>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<embed src="P/P1.pdf"></embed>
```

```js
function pr1(){
    $("embed").attr("src","P/P2.pdf");
}
pr1();
```

В консоли видно, что `src` меняется, но отображаемый pdf остается прежним.

Comment: Чиню машину, подошёл к капоту и нажал какой-то клапан, не работает, прошу помощи!

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: В сниппете ты не вызываешь `pr1`

Comment: @Grundy, по факту я его вызываю, src меняется, но pdf на новый не меняется

Comment: Вызываешь по кнопке?

Comment: @Grundy, да, по onclick

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2493706/2881286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<embed>` и `<object>` два похожих элемента, которые используются в специальных случаях (видео, аудио, flash, activeX, ...). Из-за этого в некоторых браузерах они могут обрабатываться не так как обычные DOM элементы. Поэтому изменение `src` может делать не то, что ожидалось, либо совсем ничего не делать.

В качестве решения можно удалить нужный элемент `<embed>` изменить `src` и вставить опять.

<sub>перевод ответа: [JavaScript: Changing src-attribute of a embed-tag](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0eisvuaSnHmXz7c7yt7?p=preview)</sub>

[**Пример на plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O0eisvuaSnHmXz7c7yt7?p=preview)